# Make jqgrid fill column with data derived from the one passed as 'data'

Tags: javascript, jquery, jqgrid

I am making a jqgrid using datatype local - a json array returned from the server.

```
jQuery("#my_table").jqGrid(
                        { datatype: "local", 
                          colNames: ['ID', 'Name','Status', 'Date'],
                          colModel:[ {name:'id',index:'id', width:50, sorttype:"int"}, 
                                     {name:'name',index:'name', sorttype:"string"}, 
                                     {name:'status',index:'status', width:50, sorttype:"string"}, 
                                     {name:'date',index:'date', width:120, align:"left",sorttype:"date"} ], 
                          data: result,
                          ...});
```

However, one of the columns - status - is represented as numbers.

I would like to display this data as the respective strings. For example 'Active' for status = 1 and 'Inactive' for status = 0.

Is it possible to do this directly in jqgrid, for example as additional colModel parameter or jqgrid method?
I have read through the documentation of jqgrid and failed to notice way of addressing this problem.

I don't want to change the data returned from the server, as I don't see any point in passing redundant information.

I would also prefer if I don't have to manipulate the `result` array in javascript directly as I don't see point in traversing the array 2 times (once to change the status and the second for jqgrid loading).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [formatter: "select"](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki%3apredefined_formatter#formatter_type_select):

```js
{name:'status',index:'status', width:50, 
    formatter:'select', editoptions: {value:'0:Inactive;1:Active'}}
```

Answer (score 1):

Somewhere in js code:

```
var status_lines = ['Inactive', 'Active'];
function status_formatter(cellvalue, options, rowObject) {
    return status_lines[cellvalue];
}
```

Then in colModel:

```
{name:'status',index:'status', width:50, sorttype:"string", formatter:status_formatter}
```

And of course, you can just do this in `formatter:function(c,o,r){...}` style if you prefer that.

Comment: Thanks for the tip, this is a more general solution than the one I need, but I'll be using it in other cases!

Comment: you're welcome) yes, the other solution fits better in your case, I just didn't know it.